# nested diagrams in TikZ-cd

Tags: tikz-cd

Since the last update, the following code does not compile anymore

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
UL
\arrow{r}{{\begin{tikzcd}1\arrow{r}{a}&2\end{tikzcd}}}
&UR
\\
DL
\arrow{r}
&DR
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

with the error message

> Package pgf Error: No shape named tikz@f@2-2-1 is known.

The strange thing is that if there is only the first arrow, the code compile and gives the desired diagram.

Moreover, if I use the syntax`\arrow[r, "{\begin{tikzcd}1\arrow{r}{a}&2\end{tikzcd}}"]` for the first arrow, the code does not compile even with only one arrow.
This time the error message is

> TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255].
>    \bgroup

Edit : the above code do not compile with pgf 3.0 and tikc-cd 0.9 (latest versions), but did compile with TeXLive 2013 and previous version of pgf and tikz-cd.

Comment: I don't think it's possible: `tikz-cd` uses a global naming scheme for nodes, so it gets confused by the reference to the same node in two places.

Comment: No errors with `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian) (format=pdflatex 2013.12.2)` on Ubuntu 13.04

Comment: @egreg It was possible ! But not after I updated pgf to version 3.0 (and maybe some update of tikz-cd too).
N.B. I have pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 too (TeX Live 2013/Mac)

Comment: @Matsaya You're right: I tried with TeX Live 2012 and the diagram is produced, although I'm not sure the result is what you'd want. So I guess that PGF 3.0 has broken it.

Comment: @Matsaya: Did you try with the latest tikz-cd (0.9, uploaded on CTAN 2014/03/02), that is built upon pgf 3.0?

Comment: @Bernard Yes. Specifically, it does not work with latest version of pgf and tikz-cd. See the edit.

Comment: Ampersand handling seems completely broken with the new tikz-cd. About to ask about it.

Comment: By “completely broken” I mean ampersands (and `ampersand replacement`) don't work if the `tikzcd` environment is at all nested (even just nesting it in `gathered` is enough). I suspect we're looking at the same bug. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163895/ampersands-broken-in-tikz-cd-0-9

Comment: @LukeMaurer There is indeed something broken, but our problems are different. I try the solution of David Carlisle in your link and, sadly, it does not solve my problem.

Comment: I could fix this, but I wonder whether there is a good reason to allow nested diagrams.  It might be more robust to give an error message if the user even tries to do that. Would anybody object?

Comment: @egreg: actually, you can't nest pgf matrices, but what happens is that `\arrow` works by saving code that is executed after the matrix is finished.  That is why it is possible to "nest" diagrams in this way.

Comment: @FlorêncioNeves Nice to now the comportement of '\arrow'.
For your question, I have 2-3 diagrams where arrows are labeled by others commutative diagrams (they are of course more complex than the example I gave).
But nevertheless, to give an error message is a good solution.

Answer (score 5):

Since tikz-cd 0.9 and pgf 3.0 apparently broke the possibility to nest tikz-cd diagram (even in an other environment that uses &, see Luke Maurer comment) I came with this non-elegant and manual solution :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
UL
\arrow{r}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node(1){1}; 
        \node(2)[right of=1]{2};
        \draw[->](1)--node{a} (2);
    \end{tikzpicture}}
%\arrow[r, "{\begin{tikzpicture}
%   \node(1){1}; 
%   \node(2)[right of=1]{2};
%   \draw[->](1)--node{a} (2);
%\end{tikzpicture}}"]
&UR
\\
DL
\arrow{r}
&DR
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

That is, it is still possible to use a tikzpicture environment in a \arrow (with either the old or the new syntax for the arrow).

I put this solution in case someone want a working solution, but I still hope that there is a more elegant way to do this.