# Ampersands broken in tikz-cd 0.9?

Tags: tikz-cd

I was just upgraded to `tikz-cd` 0.9 (with `pgf` 3.0.0). The following code now breaks:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{gathered}
    \begin{tikzcd}
      1 & 2 \\
      3 & 4
    \end{tikzcd}
    \\
    \begin{tikzcd}
      5 & 6 \\
      7 & 8
    \end{tikzcd}
  \end{gathered}
\]
\end{document}
```

---

```
Runaway argument?
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of \pgfutil@ifnextchar.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.11     \begin{tikzcd}
```

It works if either I comment out the `gathered` environment (and the `\\` between the diagrams) or I put the old `tikz-cd.sty` in the directory with the `.tex` file. It does *not* work to do this:

```
  \begin{gathered}
    \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
      1 \& 2 \\
      3 \& 4
    \end{tikzcd}
    \\
    \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
      5 \& 6 \\
      7 \& 8
    \end{tikzcd}
  \end{gathered}
```

That doesn't even change the error:

```
Runaway argument?
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of \pgfutil@ifnextchar.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.11     \begin{tikzcd}
                       [ampersand replacement=\&]
```

In fact, I originally ran across this when some code of mine that uses `ampersand replacement` broke.

Comment: The forbidden control sequence that is found is `\endtemplate`, which means bad news. `:-(`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If in doubt add an

```
ifnum0=`}
```

group

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}


\let\oldtikzcd\tikzcd
\def\tikzcd{{\ifnum0=`}\fi\oldtikzcd}

\let\oldendtikzcd\endtikzcd
\def\endtikzcd{\oldendtikzcd\ifnum0=`{\fi}}



\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{gathered}
    {\begin{tikzcd}
      1 & 2 \\
      3 & 4
    \end{tikzcd}}
    \\
    \begin{tikzcd}
      5 & 6 \\
      7 & 8
    \end{tikzcd}
  \end{gathered}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yikes! Er … do I want to know how that works? :-) It does work, though. Thanks!

Comment: @LukeMaurer If you look at the source of any tabular-like environment you will that kind of grouping which is needed so that TeX keeps track of which `&` belongs to which environment. You should report it as a bug in tikz-cd

Comment: I'm not sure where to report the bug—couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Comment: @LukeMaurer I had a note from the package author to say this should now be fixed in a version uploaded to ctan.